# How to store and restore cookies for multiple browser instances in CefSharp

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, cefsharp

**Application goal**

I'm trying to implement multiple browser instances in one application. On startup they should load the cookies and their cache from the previous run of the application.

**Environment**

I'm using **Visual Studio 2017** and my solution is created on **.NET 4.5.2**, using the NuGet-package of **CefSharp.Wpf 71.0.2** (http://cefsharp.github.io/).

**Attempts**

- In CefSharp you can set a global path for the CookieManager (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown). This results in every browser instance using the same cache and cookies.
- Also there is a chapter about **browser isolation** (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation) but it does not work in my case (see example).

**Example**

I tried it simply by creating multiple CefSharp browser instances, addressing WhatsApp web.

```xml
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="w1" Grid.Row="0" Address="https://web.whatsapp.com/"/>
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="w2" Grid.Row="0" Address="https://web.whatsapp.com/"/>
```

To isolate the browsers from another I set the RequestContexts of each browser instance after the MainWindow initialization.

```cs
w1.RequestContext = new RequestContext(new RequestContextSettings { CachePath = "...../w1", PersistSessionCookies = true });
w2.RequestContext = new RequestContext(new RequestContextSettings { CachePath = "...../w2", PersistSessionCookies = true });
```

This **results** in isolation for each browser but not persistence as it does not load the data after relaunching the application.

Edit: Log output
https://pastebin.com/W2KFcHyT
https://pastebin.com/BaJxJGYQ

Comment: Please provide a mode detailed example of the code you are using. The two lines out of context don't mean much. What is `cachePath`? You you using a different cache for each folder? If not then what does your `CustomRequestContextHandler` implementation look like.

Comment: There is no more code. It's a simple application with a CefSharp browser instance and a few lines of code as my two lines above.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I need more detail to help you, two lines taken out of context don't give me enough information.

Comment: I extended my question.

Comment: Much better, thanks. See if the log file says anything https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file Are the two different cache directories created?

Comment: Added my log (verbose) output

Comment: Are the two different log folders created? Is there anything in them. I don't really have time to go through the verbose log instance, generates way too much meaningless data.

Comment: Sorry, should be cache folders

Comment: Yeah the folders are created and filled but it does not load them on start.

Comment: If the folders are created then `CefSharp` is passing the values correctly to `CEF`, so might be a bug in `CEF`. Try the `73.1.120-pre01` release and see if it's been fixed in a newer version. If I have time I'll look later, probably a week from now. Remember that `CefSharp` is just a wrapper around https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef

Comment: Working like a charm. But now I got heavy stutters.. :D

Comment: @marc Did you resolve this issue by updating to a more recent CEF version? If so, consider self answering to close this question?